# Is it possible to have file upload using pure ABAP CDS and SAP Fiori Elements?

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori, cds

I would like to try uploading a file in a generated SAP Fiori Elements app using pure ABAP CDS. I know that I can create a file upload dialog in a Freestyle app, but that is not what I'm looking for.

Having the upload feature be generated from ABAP CDS would be ideal, using some form of extension point would be permissible too.

Any ideas?

Comment: The short answer is "no" or at least not out of the box using Fiori Elements but I suggest to add more details as: which kind of Fiori Element (OVP, List Report, Analytical List Page)? How a file upload is relevant in a read-only app (I am assuming it's read only because you mentioned the "pure" ABAP CDS. Fiori Elements do have some ways of placing your own content and in case you follow that approach you would implement the file upload (regardless of your intention with it) pretty much on the same way as a freestyle app.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this

```
...
  @Semantics.mimeType: true
  mimetype                as Mimetype,
  filename                as Filename,
  @Semantics.largeObject:
  { mimeType: 'Mimetype',
  fileName: 'Filename',
  contentDispositionPreference: #INLINE }
  attachment              as Attachment,
...
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yXny1.png)
with these two buttons you can realize upload/drop file